# Is there a React higher order component to replace someData.map(functionReturningComponent)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, higher-order-components

I find code like this to be hard to read:

```js
<Row>
  <Column>
    {someData.map((value, idx) => (
      <Component key={idx}>
        <ChildComponent value={value.foo}/>
        <ChildComponentTwo value={value.bar}/>
      </Component>
    )}
  </Column>
</Row>
```

Is there a HOC to replace Array.prototype.map? Say, `List` that takes a component and generates N components given an array of N items of data mappable to the props of the passed-in component?

```js
declare const data: {value:string}[]

const MyComponentList = List(MyComponent)

<Row>
  <Column>
    <MyComponentList data={data}/>
  </Column>
</Row>

and then Component = ({foo, bar}) => (<>
  <ChildComponent value={foo}/>
  <ChildComponentTwo value={bar}/>
</>)
```

Now I don't need `map` anywhere except I guess in the definition of `List`. The JSX is much easier to read. But when I search things like "HOC react replace array map JSX" I don't find anything. I suppose `List` should also inject `key={idx}` into the "child" components where `idx` comes from `dataArray.map(dataToGoToChild, idx) => <ChildComponent key={idx} {...dataToGoToChild}/>`

Comment: Not a higher order component, but are you asking for something like React Native's [FlatList](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist), but for React only?